# knitr in R Markdown failing to recognise standard commands

Tags: r, function, markdown, knitr

This code works fine in R script but fails in R Markdown

```
#Examine and clean data file
colnames(act_dat)  # Read the column names
View(act_dat)
act_dat <- clean_names(act_dat)  # Clean the names
colnames(act_dat)  # Review the results
```

I get the following error message
Quitting from lines 55-60 [chunk 3]
Error in `clean_names()`:
! could not find function "clean_names"
Execution halted

What is wrong?

I ran the code in an R Script file and it worked entirely

I ran it in R Markdown and it stopped at view(act_data) but when I changed it o View(act_data) it got as far as
act_dat <- clean_names(act_dat)
and stopped with the message:  ! could not find function "clean_names"

Comment: you have to add `library(janitor)` before using `clean_names`

Comment: or use `janitor::clean_names()` in your `rmd` chunks.